# pssh (Parallel-ssh) passing different parameter for every host

Tags: shell-script, openssh, parallel-ssh

I have a file called `hosts` which looks as follow:

```
host1
host2
host3
host4
.....
```

On these machines there is also a local user named as the machine name.  `host1` user is created on `host1` host and so on.

Is there a way to lock all these user accounts on all machines?

What I've used seems not to work properly.

```
pssh -h hosts -l root -i passwd -l hostname |cut -d. -f1
```

With this command I am hoping to lock each user account corresponding on each hostname.

I hope you get the idea of what I mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the command on the remote host, using the `HOSTNAME` variable to determine the host.

```
pssh -h hosts -l root -i 'passwd -l "$(hostname)"'
```

This assumes that the name of the user account to lock is what the machine thinks of as its name. If you're using nicknames in your SSH configuration and you want to use the nickname in the command rather than the machine's actual host name, or if the host name differs from the DNS host name, you can use `$PSSH_HOST` instead of `$(hostname)`, but only if the remote host's server configuration allows passing that variable name in the environment, which is not the case by default on many systems.

Comment: +1. probably want to use `hostname -s` there to get the short hostname (without the domain).  OP tried `hostname | cut -d. -f1`, but `hostname -s` is easier.

Comment: Guys this worked perfectly!  Thank you.  Also the hint using `-s` makes the answer complete.  Thank you too @cas

Answer (score -1):

`pssh` will read your ~/.ssh/config file. If you are using OpenSSH 5.6+ You should specify your users as options in your config file. `%h` will expand to the hostname with OpenSSH 5.6 and newer. You can use this snippet to always use the user named after the hostname with

```
host*
    User %h
```

If all of your servers always have users named after the hosts you could use

```
*
    User %h
```

If you're using and older version of OpenSSH (you should update) you can manually specify users for the hosts with

```
host1
    User host1
host2
    User host2
...
```

Comment: That's not going to help: the user is always root; the goal is to use the machine name in the command.

Comment: Indeed you are right. I didn't understand the question when I first read the command. I think a for loop would be easier to do than pssh but maybe there's still a way to do them all at once.